# Empty log files after using logkeys

Tags: 13.04, files, log

Why do I have empty log files after I start the keylogging process? I am using Ubuntu 13.04 and here are the steps I took:

`touch test.log`
`sudo logkeys -s -o test.log`

I would test it out by typing random words on the google bar and searching other stuff. I would also open up another terminal and type:

`tail --follow test.log`

where I would also type in random words. After this, I stopped logkeys by this code:

`sudo logkeys -k`

Then I would look at my log file to see if it worked and saw that it was blank! Is there any way that I can fix this so I can be able to view my logs?

Comment: Still need an answer?

Answer (score 0):

You must open the log file as root. Enter this in the terminal:

```
sudo gedit /var/log/logkeys.log
```